# command line arguments fed from an array

Tags: bash, for-loop, parameter-passing, imagemagick-convert

I'd like to perform a complicated bash command, using data fed from a long array as arguments. I guess it has to use a subshell in some way.

For example, instead of the workable 
`convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white -draw "point 1,1" -draw "point 4,8" -draw "point 87,34" etc etc etc image.png`

I want to employ a different logic where the arguments are given in the same command, more like

`convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white $(for i in 1,1 4,8 87,34 etc etc; -draw "point $i"; done) image.png`
which doesn't work, as the $i is interpreted as a command insted of an argument.

Please note that "for i in ...; do convert ...$i...; done" will not work. The `-draw "point x,y"` series of arguments must be in the same single run convert command, as convert doesn't accept -draw parameter in existing images.

Comment: You need to `echo`/`printf` the `-draw ...` string from the embedded `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build up an array of `-draw` arguments first.

```
for pt in 1,1 4,8 87,34; do
    points+=(-draw "point $pt")
done
convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white "${points[@]}" image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your command line short and clean by pumping MVG drawing commands into `convert` via its `stdin` by using the `@` file specifier followed by a dash representing `stdin` like this:

```
for i in 1,1 4,8 87,34; do 
   echo point $i
done | convert -size 100x100 xc:red -draw @- result.png
```

[image]

Or, if you have an array called `points`:

```
points=(1,1 4,8 87,34)

printf "point %s\n" ${points[@]} | convert -size 100x100 xc:red -draw @- result.png
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using `printf` to expand the content?

```
points=(1,1 4,8 87,34)
printf -- '-draw "point %s" ' ${points[@]}
```

returns the following string (without a new line at the end):

```
-draw "point 1,1" -draw "point 4,8" -draw "point 87,34"
```

You can say:

```
points=(1,1 4,8 87,34)
convert ... "$(printf -- '-draw "point %s" ' ${points[@]})" image.png
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This way, you store the points in an array and `printf` "delivers" it to the `convert` command.

Comment: Thank you, however the syntax is `-draw "point x,y"` with a dash. When I try `printf '-draw ...'` printf recognises it as a -d option and returns an error. I tried to work around it with the syntax `printf ' -draw ...'` and then, I don't know why, convert recognises it as a filename and returns `convert: unable to open image ` -draw "point etc etc`

Comment: @Voprosnik the way to avoid `printf` understand `-d` as an option is to add `--` after it, so it knows no more arguments are given --> `printf -- '-draw "point %s" ' ${points[@]}`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use expansion instead of subshell like this:

```
echo -draw\ \"point\ {1\,1,2\,2,3\,3}\"
```

produces this output:

```
-draw "point 1,1" -draw "point 2,2" -draw "point 3,3"
```

Comment: This makes `-draw "point 1,1"` a single argument, not two separate arguments `-draw` and `point 1,1` that `covert` will expect.