# Shell Script split concatenate and re-use

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ifs

In Shell script I want to achieve something like below:

```
str="india,uk,us,uae"
```

I want to split it and concatenate each item as below and assign to some variable

```
newstr = '-myParam="india" -myParam="uk" -myParam="us" -myParam="uae"'
```

so that I can use above concatenated string in my next command as below

```
curl "admin/admin" "localhost" $newstr.
```

I found a way using local IFS and for loop but the variable updated inside loop is not retaining value outside of loop because it runs in a separate bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the params into an array:

```
IFS=, read -a params <<< "$str"
```

And then loop through them and store the command in an array:

```
for i in "${params[@]}"; do
   command+=(-myparam=\"$i\")
done
```

Now you can expand it using `printf "${command[@]}"`:

```
$ printf "%s " "${command[@]}"
-myparam="india" -myparam="uk" -myparam="us" -myparam="uae"
```

That is, now you have to say:

```
curl "admin/admin" "localhost" "${command[@]}"
```

This is based on this answer by chepner: [command line arguments fed from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36864476/1983854).

Comment: It it weren't for the quotes, we could use `"${params[@]/#/-myparam=}"`.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that OP really wants those quotes. But there aren't enough details to hazard a definite opinion. The array substitution suggestion has lots of merit.

Comment: IFS=, read -a params <<< "$str" will reset the delimeter globally or only for this statement ?

Comment: @Ronnie just for this statement. You can test by saying `IFS=, read -a params <<< "a,b,c"` and then `read -a params <<< "a,b,c"`. After each one, execute `printf "%s\n" "${params[@]}"`. Prepending `IFS` to a command makes it affect just the scope of the command.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You were right. I did not want the quotes and used the one line that you mentioned which solved my other issues with for loop. :)

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui for the quicky reply.

Answer (score 3):

```
str="india,uk,us,uae"
var=-myparam=\"${str//,/\" -myparam=\"}\"
echo $var
```

Comment: I believe this is the best and simplest way to go about it

Comment: I believe this is the simplest and shortest answer. But could you give a little explanation when you have time? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code would do :

```
$ str="india,uk,us,uae"
$ newstr=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=","}{printf "-myParam=\"%s\" ",$1}' <<<"$str")
$ echo "$newstr"
-myParam="india" -myParam="uk" -myParam="us" -myParam="uae"
```

Also when you pass new string as parameter to curl, double quote it to prevent word splitting and globbing, so do :

```
curl "admin/admin" "localhost" "$newstr"
```

**Note:**  `<<<` or herestring is only supported in a few shells (Bash, ksh, or zsh) if I recall correctly. If your shell does not support it use `echo,pipe` combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=',' read -ra a <<< "${str//,/\",}";
curl "admin/admin" "localhost" "${a[@]/#/ -myParam=\"}\""
```

#### Explanation:

Starting with:

```
str="india,uk,us,uae";
```

Next, split the string into an array, using parameter substitution to insert `"` before each comma:

```
IFS=',' read -ra a <<< "${str//,/\",}";
```

Finally, we can get `newstr` through parameter substitution (while also appending the final `"`):

```
newstr="${a[@]/#/ -myParam=\"}\"";
```

`newstr` is now set to `'-myParam="india" -myParam="uk" -myParam="us" -myParam="uae"'`. We can skip the previous step and go straight to:

```
curl "admin/admin" "localhost" "${a[@]/#/ -myParam=\"}\""
```